# Conditional @click for <th> in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

How can I conditionally enable/disable `@click` with `v-if`/`v-else` while iterating through with `v-for` on a `<th>`?

I have the following code:

```
<template>
  <div id="TableHeaderDiv" class="TableHeaderClass">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th
            v-for="column in columns"
            v-bind:key="column.DataField"
            @click="sortBy(column.DataField)"
            :class="{ active: sortKey == column.DataField }"
            :style="{ width: column.Width }"
          >
            {{ column.DisplayText }}
            <div v-if="!column.isControl">
              <span
                class="arrow"
                :class="sortOrders[column.DataField] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'"
              ></span>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

I would like to write a condition so that `v-if="!column.isControl"` ... add the `@click` to the `<th>`.

My initial approach was to do something like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="TableHeaderDiv" class="TableHeaderClass">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <div v-for="column in columns" v-bind:key="column">
            <th
              v-if="!column.isControl"
              @click="sortBy(column.DataField)"
              :class="{ active: sortKey == column.DataField }"
              :style="{ width: column.Width }"
            >
              {{ column.DisplayText }}
              <div v-if="!column.isControl">
                <span
                  class="arrow"
                  :class="sortOrders[column.DataField] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'"
                ></span>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th v-else :style="{ width: column.Width }">
              {{ column.DisplayText }}
            </th>
          </div>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

But this just created a handful of `<div>` elements which is not what I intend to do.

Perhaps I am missing a fundamental concept with conditional rendering. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you need an extra 'element' to hold a `v-for` or `v-if` use `<template>`. It will be omitted from the resulting DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Vue.js 2.6 or higher you can pass `null` to the `@click` directive, and thus click listener will not be bound.

> More details can be found in this [RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0003-dynamic-directive-arguments.md?source=post_page---------------------------#handling-of-null-as-special-value). Conveniently, if the argument
> value is null, the binding/listener will be removed.

So your code could look something like this:
`v-on="{ [!colum.isControl ? 'click' : null]: sortBy(column.DataField) }"`

Comment: The code provided will still add a `click` listener it just won't do anything. The RFC is referring to the ability to make the *argument* `null`, i.e. `v-on:[null]=...`.

Comment: An attribute name can't contain spaces: see the drawbacks section of the RFC. I think your original code was fine it just wasn't related to the RFC. If avoiding creating the listener at all was really important I'd probably favour using `v-on` with an object instead.

Comment: i think it would be simpler to just do this: `@click="!column.isControl ? sortBy(column.DataField) : null`.